# Tomcat service: Update 'path of executable' via command line

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, command-line

Apache Source: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

I want to update the path to executeable via command line

```
tomcat8 //US//TestService --DisplayName="TestService2" ^ --Install="..\Tomcat\x64\bin\tomcat8.exe"
```

Result: DisplayName is updated. Install is not.

Hint: I want to update from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8.

Any ideas what the issue might be?